# Likelihood that third set is alike first or second

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have been doing tests doing side channel attacks test for my thesis and my test results are unclear. I have measured two distributions, one for a valid and one for a non-valid input to a system. The distributions are different (obviously) but not very much.

#### What I am wondering:

How can one calculate the probability of a third distribution being either of type **one** or **two**? I neither know what principal I would have to look for nor how to call this. An attacker would use this to determine if their input was of type "valid" or "non-valid". I want to know how

The only glimpse I have is what I barely understand about [cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) as a loss function in machine learning which uses the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). As I understand it can be used to compare two distributions and will yield a similarity of some sort, so I should be able to compare the similarity of distribution number **three** to each previously obtained distribution and at least determine to which it is more similar. But that wouldn't tell me how likely that is correct assumption.

I have also never had to apply it by hand (so to say) because I have been using Keras doing machine learning.

I would love for an explanation of even just a pointer as to what that is called I am trying to find out, so I can research it. Please also suggest improvements to my title as people coming in might have expected what I am asking

Comment: I voted to close, suggesting you post instead at stats.stackexchange.com, perhaps with more explicit content about the data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your distributions are discrete, you can try different approaches.

For example, [Kolmogorov Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)

Please see [Goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) in general and chi-square goodness of fit test in particular.

A nice discussion is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88764/test-for-difference-between-2-empirical-discrete-distributions)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Reading up now. My measurements are in units of milliseconds and therefore continuous but I assume converting them to a discrete scale by creating bins of say 500ms is a valid option. 
(Problem then is that I only have 18 data points per distribution.)